# How to use addEventListener for div that is created in Javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I tried to do it like this:

```js
const cards=document.querySelectorAll(".card")
for(const card of cards){
    card.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        console.log("Hello")
    })
}
```

Here I have created the div, which has a class name card.

```js
const createCard=(data)=>{
    const div=document.createElement("div")
    div.classList.add("card")
    div.innerHTML=`
    <h1>${data.name}</h1>
    <img src=${data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default} alt=${data.name}></img>
    <p>${data.base_experience}</p>
    `
    return div
}
```

I want that when we click any card then Hello will be printed in the console, but it is not working and it is not showing any error. I tried using `document.getElementsbyClassName` too, but still no output is shown. What is the problem with this. We can't apply Event listener to a div?

I tried with a button and the same code is working. Then why it is not working with div?

Comment: In what order does this code run? If you add event listeners to all the cards on the page, and then add cards, that would behave like this. You may need to remember to attach the event listener to new cards when you attach them to the dom.

Comment: You probably want [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

Comment: In `createCard` you can use `div.addEventListener` after adding `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

there might be an issue with "event delegation" if you are creating these divs dynamically (e.g., after the page has initially loaded). In that case, you should apply the event listener to the document or a static parent element that contains these divs and then check which element with the "card" class was actually clicked. Here's how you can do it:

```
// Add an event listener to the document (or a static parent element).
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('card')) {
    // Only if the clicked element has the "card" class.
    console.log('Hello');
  }
});

// Function to create the card div.
const createCard = (data) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('card');
  div.innerHTML = `
    <h1>${data.name}</h1>
    <img src="${data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default}" alt="${data.name}">
    <p>${data.base_experience}</p>
  `;
  return div;
};
```

This way, the event listener is applied to the document but checks if the clicked element has the "card" class before performing the desired action. This should work correctly even for dynamically created divs. I hope it helps you

Comment: It's generally best to use [`Event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) when using event delegation, to make sure you're checking the element that has the event listener bound to it. Otherwise, clicks on nested elements may not trigger your function as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This code of yours ...

```
const cards=document.querySelectorAll(".card")
for(const card of cards){
    card.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        console.log("Hello")
    })
}
```

only add `.addEventListener` to `.card` that currently have in HTML not include `.card` you will create later with `createCard(data)`

So you need to add `.addEventListener` to evey `.card` you create.

```
const createCard=(data)=>{
    const div=document.createElement("div")
    div.classList.add("card")
    div.innerHTML=`
    <h1>${data.name}</h1>
    <img src=${data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default} alt=${data.name}></img>
    <p>${data.base_experience}</p>
    `
    div.addEventListener('click',()=>console.log("Hello")) //add this
    return div
}
```